# SSRS - Filter with blank values

Tags: reporting-services

In one of my SSRS report, I am having a parameter with available values linked to a dataset.
This dataset is filtered based on another parameter list (cascading selection).

My problem is that I would need the available value of my parameters to be filtered and add the blank value.

[image: filters]

so in my example, I would need the list of all my dataset, filtered by the depot but to have the blank value as well.

how can we work around it?

I am trying to get a "iif" statement in me filter expression to return a "1" or a "0" but I  can't manage to get the "IN" operator in the Expression field.

Answer (score 0):

The InStr (in String) function can be used to determine if one string is found within another string. JOIN would be used to combine the values from the Paramters into a single string.

Then the IIF would check for the fields in the paramter string or a blank depot value.

```
=IIF(InStr(Join(Parameters!Depot.Label, "|"), Fields!depot.Value) > 0 OR Fields!depot.Value = "", 1, 0)
```